# Update row if there is a value or insert if not

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where the user inserts data but they can go back to the same page to edit their information. My table structure is:
`id (auto int index),
user id (links to other tables),
Doc_Name, 
Abstract`

I have an insert query:

```
$user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
$Doc_Name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Doc_Name']);
$abstract = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract']);

$the_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `document` (`user_id`,`Doc_Name`,`abstract`) VALUES
('%d','%s','%s')", $user_id, $Doc_Name, $abstract);
```

However, if their is already a row for this user_id then I want the update query instead:

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE document SET `Doc_Name` = '$Doc_Name', 'abstract='$abstract'
 WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, so the user knows what they entered, I tried to use this echo in the text box but that didn't work either,

```
<textarea name="Doc_Name" style="width:500px; height:150px" type="text" id="Doc_Name"
value="<? echo $row_settings['Doc_Name']; ?>"  size="300"> </textarea>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question, or are you just posting code?

Comment: yes my question is how do I insert but if there is already a row then update.

Comment: See my answer of how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   c=c+1;

Comment: Neat-o. That's a lot quicker than looking the old row up. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

for the textarea you can use

```
<textarea name="Doc_Name" style="width:500px; height:150px" type="text" id="Doc_Name" size="300"><? echo $row_settings['Doc_Name']; ?></textarea>
```

everything between the tags is displayed and editable

EDIT: to the other posters: nice, did not know [INSERT ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: it says undefined index:doc_Name in the box now

Comment: since the other parts are static html I suppose $row_settings['Doc_Name'] is not defined

Comment: so i need to define  $row_settings['Doc_Name']? how?

Answer (score 0):

the query:

```
SELECT * FROM document WHERE id='{$SESSION['user_id']}'
```

php:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query)) > 0) {
    //code to be executed if id exists
}
```

Comment: Did you test your code? Try it: `echo "SELECT * FROM document WHERE id='$SESSION['user_id']'";`

Comment: Then try this: `echo "SELECT * FROM document WHERE id='{$SESSION['user_id']}'";` or concat your session var.